# filter excel data using vba

Tags: vba, excel

my concept is first i have to enter text as Engine in excel at (12,3) then from g13 to end column have to search for 0,* if it is found that particular column containing 0 or * should read the value present in the 3 and 4th row text value and it should be placed at (13,3) I HAVE explained the concept in image file [spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfiE3.jpg) i have also written code but the result is not up to the level please help in this project .

```
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim FinalRow As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
With Cells(12, 3)
.Value = "Engine"
.Font.Size = 14
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastColumn As Integer
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = 13 To lastrow
Set searchRange = Range("G13:ZZ20000")
Set Rng = searchRange.Find(What:="0", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
firstaddress = Rng.Address
Rng.Offset(i, -5).Value = Rng.Offset(-11, ActiveCell.Column).Value
Next i
```

with regards,
karthikeyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastColumn As Long, i As Long
    Dim strng As String, resStrng As String

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(12, 3)
            .Value = "Engine"
            .Font.Size = 14
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 13 To lastrow
            resStrng = ""
            For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(i, "G"), .Cells(i, lastColumn))
                If cell.Value = "*" Or cell.Value = 0 Then
                    strng = .Cells(2, cell.Column) & .Cells(3, cell.Column)
                    If InStr(resStrng, strng) = 0 Then resStrng = resStrng & strng & "&"
                End If
            Next cell
            If resStrng <> "" Then .Cells(i, 3) = Left(resStrng, Len(resStrng) - 1)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```